# Significance of the T-value in parametric line-segment plane intersections

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I wrote some code a while ago to solve line-segment plane intersections but forgot to comment it. I would like someone to check my thinking is sounds.

Basically the algorithm goes like this:

1) Get two points representing the start and end of the line segment $$P0, P1$$

2) Convert these points into a parametric line representation to get:
$$(a+bt),(c+dt),(e+ft)$$ by doing $$P0 + t(P1 – P0)$$

3) Substitute the expression, $$(a+bt),(c+dt),(e+ft)$$ into our Cartesian plane equation, $$ax+by+cz=g$$ to get $$(a+bt),(c+dt),(e+ft)=g$$

4) Solve for t

5)plug our t value back into the parametric line to get the point of intersection.

I am also interested in the value of t.

My question is this:

On this website, http://www.thepolygoners.com/tutorials/lineplane/lineplane.html, the authors state that:

If:

t > 0 and t < 1  :           The intersection occurs between the two end points

t = 0                 :           The intersection falls on the first end point

t = 1                 :           Intersection falls on the second end point

t > 1                 :           Intersection occurs beyond second end Point

t < 0                 :           Intersection happens before 1st end point.

Question 1) Is my algorithm correct?

Question 2) Is the stuff about the T-value correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: yes, correct, basically. But your notation is fouled up. You're using the symbols a, b, c in two different ways.

Question 2: yes, also correct.